# IIS Azure force HTTPS negate rule not working

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to force HTTP on my website (all domains), except for my test domain (below) but the re-write rule is kicking in each and every time no matter what combination of rules I try. Please can someone advise where I might be going wrong?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="FORCEHTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testwebsite1-test.azurewebsites.net$" negate="true" />

      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="HTTPS://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `pattern` be something like `testwebsite1-test.azurewebsites.net.*`?

Comment: IIS.Net suggests this works for localhost negate <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" /> and when I tell my rule to not negate i get infinite redirect so I suspect the pattern is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `Amor-MSFT's` comment above I decided to try the redirect again on a different PC and indeed found it working.

I then tried to break and fix the redirect by altering the URL and could not get it to work again `until I cleared my cache`.

I am using `Google Chrome` and discovered that `permanent redirects` are cached by the browser.

Hope this helps others who have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Please mark your reply as answer.  A thread which has been marked will be easier retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, I will do this tomorrow, as it won't let me mark it today.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any errors in your configuration. I tested it on my Azure Web App and it can redirect http request to https for all domains except one domain configured in condition section.

1. Please make sure you added the configuration under <system.webServer> tag.
2. Please check whether the host name which you configured in conditions section is right.